# Missed Headers folder in OpenCl.framework Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, opencl-c++

I am trying to stark work with OpenCl framework on my MacBook, and Mac OS has the framework installed, but there is no needed header cl.hpp I want to work with. I have downloaded the header from Khronos OpenCL Registry, but now I do not know where to paste it since there is no Headers folder in /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/, I've tried to find present headers (cl.h) with find in Terminal, but unsuccessful. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I fixed the problem, I noticed that cmake finds OpenCL at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework. There is folder Headers.